# SQL to Pyspark Conversion

Tags: python, database, automation, mysql

Suppose you are given a `.sql` file containing 10,000 lines of SQL commands and you were told to convert them to PySpark.

What software would you use?

...the task I want to accomplish:

- Somehow automate the creation of PySpark from a `.sql` file.

...your requirements for that task

- I get that there would most likely be an intermediary step between `.sql --> pyspark`, so the PySpark conversion is not a priority, the priority is having the `.sql` file in some sort of 'universal' model.

...what you already know about software available for this purpose

- I have has a look at relational algebra, which looks like could be the 'universal` model, but I'm not sure if that would work. See: http://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/calc/local/uibk/local/0

Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assuming such a software doesn't exist (which I am not sure of, spark users may come from SQL and have had such requirements before). What I think would need to be done if one were to write one:

1. parse the SQL. In a way that gives you a sensible model you can work with. Here is a question where exactly this is asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394998/parsing-sql-with-python
2. use the AST to generate corresponding spark commands. I think it would be enough to just output text, but bonus points if you can find a library that lets you construct a spark ast and lets you generate python code from that.

I understand that 2) is not very detailed, but as you correctly mentioned in your answer, getting the SQL in a usable model format is the first and maybe even biggest issue.

Comment: thanks for your response, it is nice to see we are saying similar things. I have found this: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/select_parser.py from your post. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Alex looks good, it seems to have structure, which is what seems to be completely lacking for Python-sqlparse. You'll have to try and see if it' already enough for your use case or whether you need to add to / change the grammar. Obviously its currently only a small subset of SQL. From what the answers were, I would have proposed either pyparsing (based on that SQL example), or https://github.com/TwoLaid/python-sqlparser - definitely try that pyparsing example though.

Comment: Okay this makes sense. I'm unsure on the AST -> Spark conversion though as I feel like that might be a tricky job.

Comment: @Alex It sure is, make sure you first have a good idea how a given SQL statement has to look in spark